# Find non-default collation on columns for all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a script I can use to find all columns in all tables in a SQL catalog that does not have the collation `<database default>` ?

I have taken over a legacy system and have different collations in the some tables and I would like to find all instances in one hit rather than going through manually.

However I don't want to change the collation programmatically as I would like to review each table one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this script here:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseCollation VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation = collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.databases
WHERE 
    database_id = DB_ID()

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation 'Default database collation'

SELECT 
    t.Name 'Table Name',
    c.name 'Col Name',
    ty.name 'Type Name',
    c.max_length,
    c.collation_name,
    c.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id    
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND 
    c.collation_name <> @DatabaseCollation
```

It checks for the database default collation and then finds any columns that don't comply with that.

Comment: Spot on, thanks very much. Will accept this as the answer as soon the "5 mins" is up!

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Great answer, I think there is a minor bug though. The join on system_type_id can create duplicate results if the database has custom types. I think the join should actually be on user_type_id.

Comment: You can also add an extra column to generate the alter table scripts if you want to change them (although this may require deleting and re-creating indices which reference fields being changed)

   'ALTER TABLE ['+t.Name+'] ALTER COLUMN ['+c.Name+'] '+ty.name+'('+convert(varchar(16),c.max_length)+') '+'COLLATE '+@DatabaseCollation+CASE WHEN c.is_nullable=1 THEN '' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END+';'

Comment: note you can get the default collection for a database with just a `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDatabase', 'Collation')`